# Measure the performance of web page

Tags: angularjs, performance, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, performancecounter

I have a web application which uses angular 1.5 with Typescripts. Angular will call web api. The api uses Entity framework. Now I want to measure the performance of the page for various events like page load, button click etc.

Is there any tool available which can provide information for time taken to execute controller action, time taken by entity framework etc?

I want tool which can provide aggregated information when page is loaded or I click on any button.

I am fine even if there are tools which can provide above information separately.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Chrome DevTools? you should check these links: [the timeline tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool) and [analyze runtime performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/analyze-runtime?hl=en).

In short: you should open the Developer tools, go to profiles and start a recording, then you perform the actions you want to measure (e.g. click a button) and stop the recording. You will see how long each of the method calls take. [Here a how to](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool#make-a-recording) on how to do recordings and a couple of tips.

There are also other options like [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

There are few tools which allows to analysis your code, watcher and digest cycle. You can also use Timeline tool in Chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-performance/hejbpbhdhhchmmcgmccpnngfedalkmkm?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

https://augury.angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple performance indicators in angular applications:

For example you can measure the digest cycle time:

```
$timeout(() => {
    angular.element(document).injector().invoke(() => {
      let start = performance.now();
      $rootScope.$apply();
      console.log(performance.now() - start);
    });
  });
```